# Multiple digital signatures

Tags: digital

I have the following case scenario: One document that needs to be signed digitally (using an external signing service) by 4 different people. The 4 people must be present while signing the document at the same place.

How can I create a situation where "digitally speaking" is ensure that the 4 people were signing while being together?

I thought that if each one of them uses the same computer (each of them logging in the signing service) that would be a way since it is the same datamachine (same IP). Is there any others?

Thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 0):

you can send that document to signing server only when users are online and there should be hi/hello kind of communication in between them via chat.

Comment: They must be physically together :)

Answer (score 0):

One PDF document can have multiple signatures. Thus you can have distinct 4 Digital Signatures for each of 4 people and sign document with digital signature of all 4 people one after another. It's like approval workflow!

You may refer to Programer's guide of PDF signing component you are using to check how to put multiple signature on single document (without invalidating previous signatures)